# how to output the current protocol and url using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a share dialog.

**On dev it looks like:**

```
http://xxxxxx.com/stuff
```

**On prod:**

```
https://yyyyyyyyyyy.com/stuff
```

What's the best rails way to output #Protocol# #URL#

And where can I set these in rails? thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
request.protocol
request.url
```

See the [request object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object).

Answer (score 2):

**request** object. you can use **request.fullpath**

API reference is [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-fullpath)

Comment: `request.fullpath` would return `/stuff` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your development.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'http'
```

and in production.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:protocol] = 'https'
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found:

```
url_for(:only_path => false)
```